# How to fix "Name or service not known(www.googleapis.com:443)"

Tags: ruby

Currently I'm updating an existing script that gets all the users in Google's AdminDirectoryV1.
This is working but suddenly it's returning errors:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
        27: from googletoldap_sync.rb:308:in `<main>'
        26: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/generated/google/apis/admin_directory_v1/service.rb:3740:in `list_users'
        25: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:360:in `execute_or_queue_command'
        24: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:102:in `execute'
        23: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        22: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        21: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        20: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:110:in `block in execute'
        19: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        18: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        17: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        16: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
        15: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/google-api-client-0.36.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:302:in `execute_once'
        14: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:854:in `request'
        13: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1104:in `follow_redirect'
        12: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
        11: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
        10: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
         9: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1242:in `do_get_block'
         8: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:177:in `query'
         7: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:511:in `query'
         6: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `connect'
         5: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
         4: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
         3: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:752:in `block in connect'
         2: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:21:in `create_socket'
         1: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:607:in `create_socket'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:625:in `rescue in create_socket': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (www.googleapis.com:443) (Google::Apis::TransmissionError)
```

I'm using the following gems:

```
require "google/apis/admin_directory_v1"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
```

Comment: You're using port `443` but it appears you're trying to use a HTTP connection. Try "https" instead. Otherwise you're not giving us enough information to help you. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: is this issue occurring currently? if not, can you explain some details of how did you fix it?